# Tkinter, update Entry widget before calling <Key> binding

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script that updates everytime a key is entered into a tkinter.Entry widget setup like so:

```
self.entrySearch.bind("<Key>", self.updateSearch)
```

The problem that I am having is that the method I've bound to `"<Key>"` is resolved before the key is entered into the Entry widget.  This means that when I call `self.entrySearch.get()`, I only get what was in the Entry box just before the last keystroke.

I've tried simple appending the character onto the end, but I can't think of a way to resolve Backspaces or Deletes, or where the character is entered mid-string.

Basically, what I'm looking for is a method to allow the entry box to update before my binding is resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the entry to a [variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Trace the variable change.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

def print_entry_value(*args):
    print(v.get())

root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
v.trace('w', print_entry_value)
e = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```